# React Stripe Elements placeholder based on i18n language

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, stripe-payments

I want to change the placeholder of the CardElement based on i18n language.
Im passing the locale as option when loading stripe

```
stripePromise = loadStripe(key, {   locale: i18nInstance.language })
```

It did work but when changing the language with the switcher it doesn't reflect on the placeholders.How can i update the options accordingly knowing that Loading Stripe in useEffect has side effects

Comment: Hello, it can be usefull if you share a little bit more code.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, more code would be helpful! Right now, the stripePromise will resolve to a Stripe.js instance which will contain the adjusted locale. You can check this by `await`-ing the Promise and logging `stripe._locale`. You need to make sure that you're then re-updating the Elements instances on your page. My guess is that you'll need to `await` the stripePromise manually, then provide the resulting Stripe.js instance to your Elements provider.

Answer (score 2):

Stripe also allows you to use the [Elements Props](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react#elements-props) to insert the locale like this:

```
<Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={ locale: i18nInstance.language }>
```

Adding the locale to options will give you more flexibility to handle this value inside the component instead of outside as they suggest for `loadStripe`.

I am not using the same library for `i18n` but here is an example with NextJs and TS

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  loadStripe,
  StripeElementLocale,
} from '@stripe/stripe-js'
import { Elements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Checkout from 'library/organisms/Checkout'

// Make sure to call `loadStripe` outside of a component’s render to avoid
// recreating the `Stripe` object on every render.
const stripePromise = loadStripe('ADD YOUR KEY')

const CheckoutPage = () => {
  const { locale } = useRouter()

  // The following line has been simplified to only check if the locale is 'en'
  // so TS don't complain but you could develope it for more languages.
  const stripeLocale: StripeElementLocale = locale === 'en' ? locale : 'auto'

  return (
    <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={ locale: stripeLocale }>
      <Checkout />
    </Elements>
  )
}

export default CheckoutPage
```

Comment: It has been a while but this issue was solved thanks @mark